# TH element with (Select All) Checkbox and TableSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, checkbox, tablesorter

I have a table with the tablesorter js applied. In two of my table header columns I have checkboxes that check yes or no on all of the rows. The issue is that since I have the tablesorter js on the table it will select or deselect all of the rows but then sort them. I want the to only select or deselect all of the checkboxes and NOT sort the columns when click on the checkbox. But when I click in the TH I still want to sort it.

In the rows there is a number next to the checkbox so that is the reason for the keeping the sorting on the columns.

I have tried adding stopPropogation and preventDefault but this has not been any luck.

Here is my JS:

```
$(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        cssInfoBlock: "tablesorter-no-sort",
        cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow"
    });

        $("#UseSuggestedSelectAll").change(function(event) {
            event.stopPropogation();
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(".suggested").prop('checked', true);
                $(".override").prop('checked', false);
                $("#OverrrideSelectAll").prop('checked', false);
                UpdateTable();

            } else {
                $(".suggested").prop('checked', false);
                UpdateTable();
            }
        });
```

Here is what one of my TH's look like (Rendered - UGLY):

```
<th id="suggested-header" style="width: 160px; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-user-select: none;" class="sort-text tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerUnSorted" data-column="0" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="stock-item-table" unselectable="on" aria-sort="none" aria-label="

                                    Use Suggested Qty
                                : No sort applied, activate to apply a descending sort"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
                                    <input id="UseSuggestedSelectAll" name="UseSuggestedSelectAll" style="vertical-align: bottom;float:right;" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="UseSuggestedSelectAll" type="hidden" value="false">
                                    <label for="Use_Suggested_Qty" style="margin-top:6px;margin-right: 5px;float:right;">Use Suggested Qty</label>
                                </div></th>
```

I am not positive but maybe it is sorting first and that is why the stopPropogation is not working? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share your HTML? Or better yet a demo of the problem? And have you seen [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4226/)? You can change the `resort` value to `false` on line 11 to prevent resorting.